# Montar proyecto laravel 5.7 en hosting

Tags: laravel

Estuve revisando en internet e incluso dentro del foro y no encuentro una respuesta sobre como debo de configurar correctamente los archivos para subir mi proyecto, lo estoy intentado subir en 1and1 (no cuenta con cpanel). Lo que he intentado es poner los archivos de la carpeta public de mi proyecto dentro de la carpeta raíz y todos los demás archivos los puse dentro de otra carpeta llamada laravel. El archivo index.php que quedo en la carpeta raíz lo modifique para poder acceder al archivo welcome.blade.php

direccion original

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

direccion modificada

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
```

direccion original

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

direccion modificada:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

hasta este punto todo bien , pero cuando intento acceder a otra ruta que no sea la principal me arroja el error "internal Server Error"

espero me puedan apoyar ya que vi un tema similar aquí mismo pero sin respuesta.

Agrego el contido del .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Intenta: require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'; y $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php'; Hasta aquí no necesitas nada mas. Para mostrar el template welcome, debes agregarlo a tu archivo de rutas para que cuando la ruta sea algo como '/' retorne esa plantilla. (poner correctamente la constante DIR)

Comment: por el archivo de rutas te refieres al index.php o routes/web.php

Comment: Bryan añadi las rutas al archivo index.php y me sigue resolviendo solo la primera pagina de welcome.blade.php en cuanto intento ingresar al login o alguna otra ruta me aparece el mismo error **Internal Server Error**

Comment: Primero la estructura (sin modificar nada, solo cambio de carpetas ) es : www.tudominio.com/laravel/* y www.tudominio.com/public/*. La carpeta laravel contiene la app y public la parte visible al publico. el index.php de la carpeta public debe ser modificado con las lineas que te dejé arriba (para cargar las clases e iniciar la aplicación). Ahora dentro de www.tudominio.com/laravel/routes/web.php debes agregar algo como esto: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
}); Es toda la configuración que necesitarías.

Comment: ya lo hice y sigo sin poder acceder al login o registrer solo al welcome

Comment: Te sale algo mas que solo el error 500? las credenciales de base de datos están correctas? migraste las tablas? que versión de PHP utilizas, tienes agregadas las exenciones necesarias para ejecutar laravel 5.7?

Comment: **Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/homepages/18/d621001430/htdocs/AFHJ/laravel/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php7.2') in /homepages/18/d621001430/htdocs/AFHJ/laravel/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66**

Las credenciales ya las verifique y si son correctas.

La base de datos la migre por backup.

PHP 7.2, no se que mas extensiones sean necesarias.

Comment: Entiendo que esta es la raiz del sitio verdad? /homepages/18/d621001430/htdocs/AFHJ/. Desde ahì tienes 2 carpetas, public y laravel. dentro de laravel, tienes la carpeta vendor?

Comment: Asi es, dentro de laravel estan todas las carpetas del proyecto, excepto public

Comment: Ok. Y en el index.php de la carpeta public tienes estas configuraciones ya? __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'; y __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php'; Todas las las rutas funcionan, excepto login y regisro? si no estas seguro, crea una ruta de pruebas que imprima algo, intenta acceder y ve si te muestra todo correctamente.

Comment: Tuve que volver a montar todo el proyecto de nuevo y verificar todas las credenciales de conexion, hacer los cambios que me sugeriste y ya pude acceder al login, registrar y al index, solo que no puedo acceder a todas las vistas porque se me cambiaron las rutas.

Comment: Que bueno. Ese ya es un problema menor o no?

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo solucione creando un archivo index que me direccionara hacia el index que genera laravel dentro de la carpeta /public. Las únicas configuraciones que cambie fueron dentro del archivo .env fueron el Host-name, DB-name, DB-user y DB-password, a parte de eso las rutas en los botones se les tuvo que agregar "/public/index.php" al inicio de cada ruta y en las imágenes agregue también al inicio de cada ruta "/../.." espero les sirva esta informacion para cuando tengan que montar un proyecto en un servidor como 1&1.

Gracias a @BryanRetamal por sus aportes!

Comment: También tengo problemas al configurar un proyecto laravel en un hosting que tengo que sale error Server Internal Error 500, he realizado los pasos pero no me sale

Comment: Es mejor hacerlo en el htacces poner la url de tu proyecto seguido de `urlweb/public/`. Es mejor así que un index.